# Control tab focus (choose next element to focus) with GTK / PyGTK

Tags: focus, pygtk, gtk, gtk2

How can I force the <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the element I want, is it possible to give my software a list of elements to cycle focus ?

I remember once using a property called `tabindex`, but I can't find it anymore.

Maybe, preventing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus an element could also work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the order of focusing for each widget in a container, using the function [`container.set_focus_chain()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcontainer.html#method-gtkcontainer--set-focus-chain).

Comment: Where can I find an example of this? Thanks